# Can't load yahoo - This XML file does not appear

Tags: xml, error-handling, yahoo

For some reason I can no longer open yahoo on my computer. I get the below error message when trying to load yahoo. I have used yahoo for many years daily as I have an e-mail account with them. Have no idea why I can no longer access yahoo on my computer.

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.


<Error>
 <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
 <Message>Access Denied</Message>
 <RequestId>ZCR480ESPWSWQ002</RequestId>
 <HostId>elw+FxM3Jlc1sLz4TnuaIJujM1LHowd/gQrVsh+ONIPb+spNqy35FiOqzUcvW/J/8byGrt5Et6c=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: Same with me. It started 1 month ago. There is a temporary fix if you delete all site cookies but after some days it reappear. I usinh yahoo from the 90s but i am thinking to shift as i has several bugs

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the **Host Id** is based on the communication area; this is an error, not a bug.

This tells you about **bad communication in the area** set based on your encrypted host to a specific request to the area based **a defined request**.
The access is based on authentication this will not damage your account.
The term **host ID is a generic term** ... in some cases that specifies the computer, hard disk drive serial number or Ethernet address in the local network.

This issue *is a similar implementation* for yahoo.

How to fix it?

... you can check if your request to yahoo is good or try to use a proxy to another area.

For example: https://ro.yahoo.com/?p=us this will send the error but this works well: https://ro.yahoo.com.